# Use Macintosh layout for external physical keyboard?

Tags: external-keyboard, localization, aosp, text-input

I'd like to connect a German Macintosh keyboard to my Android device. It uses swapped signals for `°`/`^` and `<`/`>` as well as different positions for `[`, `]`, `{`, `}` and `@`. It also has a bunch of special characters, but I don't consider those of high priority.

I tested [More Physical Keyboard Layouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=varzan.extraKeyboardLayouts), but it doesn't feature Macintosh layouts ([yet](https://github.com/calin-darie/extra-keyboard-layouts/issues/29)). I also saw the [External Keyboard Helper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper) that allows to define a custom layout, but it requires a Google Account to buy it from the Play Store, but I need a solution that works with AOSP.

(Free apps on the Play Store are fine, because I can download those anonymously using the Aurora Store.)

Answer (score 1):

If remapping some keys is enough for you take a look at [ExKeyMo](https://exkeymo.herokuapp.com). Disclaimer: I'm the developer. It can build an app with your custom layout built-in.

UPDATE:

ExKeyMo has two modes [Simple](https://exkeymo.herokuapp.com/simple) one to remap keys and [Complex](https://exkeymo.herokuapp.com/complex) one to enter custom [Key Character Map file](https://exkeymo.herokuapp.com/docs). Also there is ExKeyMo's [Docs](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/input/key-character-map-files) page.

UPDATE:

ExKeyMo web app is not available on Heroku anymore. You'll have to run it locally. See the project's page on [GitHub](https://github.com/ris58h/exkeymo-web).

Comment: It's not a bad take, but it won't work. For instance, the `@` sign is on `L` instead of `Q` using the alt/opt modifier, but I cannot swap `L` with `Q` for obvious reasons. Your solution only supports single stroke remaps, I'd need to map from shortcuts to alternative shortcuts involving multiple keys.

Comment: @MartinBraun ExKeyMo has [complex](https://exkeymo.herokuapp.com/complex) remapping. Just enter content of your custom [Key Character Map file](https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/input/key-character-map-files) in the ExKeyMo's form and click `Download` to get an app with your layout built-in. Don't forget to check ExKeyMo's [docs](https://exkeymo.herokuapp.com/docs). I will edit my answer to provide more info.